# How pass oAuth2 server URL in config/gitlab.yml under providers

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, gitlab

We have setup Gitlab and it is working well. We have our own oAuth2 server we'd like to connect to, so only those with an account in our oAuth2 server can have access to Gitlab.

We've installed omniauth-oauth2 (https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth-oauth2) and have enabled it in gitlab.yml like this:

`omniauth:
    enabled: true
    providers:
       - { name: 'oauth2' }`

When we restart gitlab we see the OAuth2 button on the login page, but the URL to our oauth2 server is wrong, and we haven't set out app_id and app_secret.

My question is: How do I pass the params and related data for app_id, app_secret and oauth2 server url via this settings file. We've tried a number of things so far, but haven't gotten very far.

Notes:

- I've never used Ruby before this week. Learned a lot so far!
- We've attempted to set additional args with args: { url:
  'url-to-our-oauth2-server' }
- I believe I need to create my own strategy file, which I plan on doing based on the supplied omniauth-oauth2 strategy file

Comment: It would appear I simply don't know what the param name is for the oauth2 server that needs setting. The app_id and app_secret params are correct and being passed through. So, how can I find out what the proper param is for setting the oauth server url?

Comment: Fixed the issue by writing our own custom strategy.

Comment: How did you solve this? You can answer your own question and it can also help the others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use our own oAuth server, we had to write our own strategy which implements omniauth, and import that via the Gemfile. The oAuth URLs are within this strategy. We then placed our oAuth keys in the /home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/devices.rb file before the last 'end' statement:

```
    end
    config.omniauth :strategy_name, "{client_id_goes_here}", "{client_key_goes_here}"
end
```

Our strategy looks something like this, replacing Strategy_name with your strategy name, and replacing site, authorize_url and token_url with your own URLs:

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Strategy_name < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2

  option :client_options, {
    :site => 'https://authserve.mydomain.com',
    :authorize_url => 'https://authserve.mydomain.com/oauth/authorize',
    :token_url => '/oauth/access_token'
  }

  def request_phase
    super
  end

  def authorize_params
    super.tap do |params|
      %w[scope client_options].each do |v|
        if request.params[v]
          params[v.to_sym] = request.params[v]
        end
      end
    end
  end

  uid { raw_info['id'].to_s }

  info do
    {
      :email => raw_info['email'],
      :name => raw_info['name'],
      :nickname => raw_info['username']
    }
  end

  extra do
    {:raw_info => raw_info}
  end

  def raw_info
    @raw_info ||= access_token.get("/v1/users?access_token=#{access_token.token}").parsed
  end

end
  end
end
```